# push item to div from list of item div

Tags: php

I have a question. I have for example list of div, i just want all these dives should be clickable. And after click on div, value from div should be pushed to on an other div. How I can do it in a best way?

```
    <?php
define('HOST','xxxx');
define('USER','xxx');
define('PASS','xxxx');
define('DB','xxxxx');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from users";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,
    array(
      'email'=>$row[3], 
));
} 
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#usersOnLine { 
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    color:black;
    border: 3px teal solid;
    height: 525px;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}

.container{
    width:970px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
<div id="reciver"><h3>reciver</h3></div>
<div id="sender"><h3>sender</h3></div>
<h2 align="right"> all contacts </h2>
<div id="usersOnLine">
<?php
foreach($result as $key => $val)
{
    echo $val['email'];
    echo "<br>";
}
 ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is useronline div in which many name are i want when i click on any name name push to reciver div how to made it i am new in php

Comment: I don't think this can be done in php alone. You'll probably need something like JavaScript

Comment: will you please edit my code how can i do this with javascript

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And why didn't it work? That would be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it with a Combination of Javascript and HTML. Below is how:

**HTML, CSS & JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY**

```
        <!-- HTML-->
        <html>
        <head>

        <!-- CSS-->
            <style>
                #usersOnLine {
                    font-family:tahoma;
                    font-size:12px;
                    color:black;
                    border: 3px teal solid;
                    height: 525px;
                    width: 250px;
                    float: right;
                    overflow-y:scroll;
                    padding: 10px;
                }

                .container{
                    width:970px;
                    height:auto;
                    margin:0 auto;
                }

                .clickAble{
                    display: inline-block;;
                    cursor:pointer;     /* <== TO INDICATE TO USER THAT THIS IS CLICKABLE... */
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <!-- HTML CONTENT -->
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="receiver">
                <h3>receiver</h3>
                <!-- NOTICE THAT THIS IS NEW NOW... -->
                <!-- IT'S IMPORTANT THAT YOU HAVE THIS PARAGRAPH EXACTLY AS IT IS HERE -->
                <p class='bubbled-data'></p>
            </div>
            <div id="sender"><h3>sender</h3></div>
            <h2 align="right"> all contacts </h2>
            <div id="usersOnLine">
                <?php
                    foreach($result as $key => $val){
                        echo "<span class='clickAble'>" . $val['email'] . "</span><br />";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <!-- THE FORM -->               
            <form id="messageForm" action="<?php echo $_PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST" >
                <input type="text" name="data" id="message" placeholder="message" onFocus="fun1(this)" onBlur="fun2(this)" required="" /><br /><br />
                <!-- NOTICE THAT WE ADDED A HIDDEN FIELD TO HOLD THE DATA -->
                <input type="hidden" name="user_data" id="user_data" value="">
                <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    var receiver    = $("#receiver");
                    var clickAbles  = $(".clickAble");

                    // BIND THE clickAble SPAN TO AN ON-CLICK EVENT...
                    // SO THAT WITH EACH CLICK, YOU CAN SIMPLE APPEND THE CONTENT OF THAT SPAN TO THE RECEIVER DIV
                    clickAbles.on("click", function(evt){
                        var nameValue       = $(this).text();
                        receiver.find(".bubbled-data").text(nameValue);

                        // ADD THE SAME VALUE TO THE HIDDEN INPUT ELEMENT: #user_data
                        $("#user_data").val(nameValue);
                    });



                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

**TEST & FIDDLE WITH IT HERE**

https://jsfiddle.net/7eres0L0/

Comment: but in my case name come from database which will be increase or decrease how can i do this ?

Comment: @Malik          No Problem... It is exactly the same principle... we just simulated an array of names because we don't have your database. just copy only the **HTML, CSS & JAVASCRIPT** Section above and it will still work just fine... because the array here is also called $result... We have now updated the HTML to look exactly like yours...

Comment: its working but problem is this i just want when i click on item it will show only that item when i click on one item its show fine but when i click on other item that will be replace

Comment: @Malik    OK.... We have now changed the Javascript + HTML Mark-up to take that into account... just try it again....

Comment: @Malik     You may now copy the newly updated **HTML, CSS & JAVASCRIPT** Section. Let us know how it went.... Good-Luck to you, my Friend...   ;-)

Comment: ok i will try thanks

Comment: will you please tell me item which i get through click how to send in form

Comment: @Malik    I don't understand your Question... can you come again... German? No Problems... French? Also no Problems ;-)

Comment: i mean how can i want to send form of the div item.

Comment: @Malik    Still don't understand... you want to save the value to the database or what? You want to have a FORM WITH A TEXT-FIELD so that the value of the Text-Field will be the Result of the name that was clicked?

Comment: yes nam that clicked i want to post it through form]

Comment: <form id="messageForm" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">
 
<input type="text" name="data" id="message"   placeholder="message" onFocus="fun1(this)" onBlur="fun2(this)" required=""   /><br /><br />
 <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

Comment: in this form i want also send click name

Comment: when page reload click value gone

Comment: hello @poiz look here when i reload page click value gone